# Using pass on multiple computers. Which pgp key to share?

Tags: password, gpg, pgp

I'm using pass password manager on multiple computers, linked via a git repository. Which pgp key do I need to share across computers, the public, private, or both, so that I can add /edit /delete passwords on all computers?

Answer (score 2):

To decrypt (read), you only need the private key.

To encrypt (write), you need the public key.

As *editing* involves both reading and writing, you need both keys.

I believe that you don't need a key to *delete* a password as they are stored as individual files (and you don't need to decrypt a file to delete it).

Comment: "to [..] **edit** [..] you need the **public key**." Can this be true? Since for editing you also need to _read_ the current password, which requires _private key_.

Comment: @alex You need to decrypt _before_ editing, if what you're editing in encrypted. Once it is decrypted, you obviously don't need the private key to edit the decrypted text. You also don't need a public key to edit anything, as editing _in it self_ does not involve decrypting or encrypting anything. I will change this and remove the word "edit" as it is confusing.

Comment: @alex I forgot the context of this question (it's quite old). I think it may be clearer now?

Comment: Thank you, and have a nice day (-:

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd consider "editing" a passphrase replacing the value for a site by another one, not regarding the old passphrase at all (which would include a read operation). `pass` stores the site's URL in the file name in plain text, thus does not require any cryptographic operations for finding/"lookup" of the encrypted content at all.

If you only want to **add, edit and delete** passwords, you only need the **public key**, to be specific for the add and edit operations which encrypt the passphrase using the public key; in fact deleting does not imply any cryptographic operations at all.

On the other hand, for **reading** any passphrase, you will need to provide the **private key**, which is required to decrypt the passphrase.

Comment: "to [..] **edit** [..] you need the **public key**." Can this be true? Since for editing you also need to _read_ the current password, which requires _private key_.

Comment: If editing displays the old content, you're definitely right. If it just replaces the old passphrase without showing, editing is a delete-then-add operation and indeed does _not_ require the private key. Not using `pass` for quite some time now and not sure any more how it works, though.