# 'pass': Easiest way to synchronize the password-store between multiple machines

Tags: security, password, password-store

I moved to the [***pass***](https://www.passwordstore.org/) password manager and I'm trying to integrate it as well as possible into my workflow. However, I'm not familiar with deeper synchronization/version-control concepts (git, password server), so I'm stuck syncing the passwords between multiple computers.

I'm using Linux (Debian 9) and the synchronization is done over the local network with Unison -- usually I'm indicating which directories should be the same and every time, before I switch, I'm syncing between the machines. Is there a possibility to **sync the *password-store* directories** – and how, considering the keys are required to use *pass*.

**Alternatively** is there a good -- easy to understand and complete -- tutorial for using the git-/server-solution? (The official [manual](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/), [article1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pass#Install_a_bare_Git_repository_for_Pass_on_the_server), [article2](https://medium.com/@chasinglogic/the-definitive-guide-to-password-store-c337a8f023a1), [article3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368473/using-pass-on-multiple-computers-which-pgp-key-to-share/368474?noredirect=1#comment1045514_368474) I found are incomplete for normal users.)

Comment: Recently I made [this](https://github.com/Al-Caveman/nsapass), you may find it useful.  With it you just need to sync one file.  It has the added benefit that password entry identifiers (path names) are not leaked as the whole thing is in a single encrypted json file, less typing (smart tag-based searching), more generic as it allows you to choose your own encryption tool (not locked to gpg), defaults to `ciphart` instead of `gpg`, which uses xchacha20 from libsodium (more modern and cleaner than gpg).  All while number of lines is approximately about that of `pass`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've followed the step by step instructions of Mathew Robinson [here](https://medium.com/@chasinglogic/the-definitive-guide-to-password-store-c337a8f023a1) and it works like a charm.

The linked article recommends making a git repository for the password store and using

```
pass git push origin master
```

to sync. Then use

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys > [name].gpg
```

to put your gpg key in a file, which you should move to the new machine. Then on the new machine you can

```
gpg2 --import [name].gpg
```

and pass commands work normally.

Comment: When importing the key I had an error message : gpg: no writable keyring found: Not found. For some reason, the ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx and ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx~ were root owned, restoring user ownership solved the issue.